# error of creating a repository:did you run git update-server-info on the server?

Tags: git, github

I'm very new to git. I wanted to create a repository named Common-Lib, below is the commands I used.

```
E:\My Doc\programming\git\Common-Lib>touch README

E:\My Doc\programming\git\Common-Lib>git init
Initialized empty Git repository in E:/My Doc/programming/git/Common-Lib/.git/

E:\My Doc\programming\git\Common-Lib>git add README

E:\My Doc\programming\git\Common-Lib>git commit -m "first commit"
[master (root-commit) 5e25a0d] first commit
 0 files changed
 create mode 100644 README

E:\My Doc\programming\git\Common-Lib>  git remote add origin https://github.com/fxbird/Common-Lib.git

E:\My Doc\programming\git\Common-Lib>git push -u origin master
fatal: https://github.com/fxbird/Common-Lib.git/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

E:\My Doc\programming\git\Common-Lib>git update-server-info

E:\My Doc\programming\git\Common-Lib>git push -u origin master
fatal: https://github.com/fxbird/Common-Lib.git/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

E:\My Doc\programming\git\Common-Lib>
```

Even after running `git update-server-info`, it still throws the same error, why is that? thanks.

Comment: That error basically means that the repository does not exist on the server. So check your GitHub profile if it really exist and fix any spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commands you've used have successfully created a repository OK on your own machine, but it doesn't exist on Github; that's why you get the error:

```
fatal: https://github.com/fxbird/Common-Lib.git/info/refs not found
```

The "refs" file isn't found because it doesn't exist. Your best solution is to create the repository on Github first and then clone it to your local machine. That way everything will be set up for you to push and pull.

Oh, and when you ran:

```
git update-server-info
```

you ran that on your local repository, not on the server so it wouldn't work anyway. That command generates files necessary to access your repository over "dumb" protocols like http.

Comment: yes,but not enough ,pull command needs to be run before running push command, see http://webvulture.wordpress.com/2009/10/13/rejected-master-master-non-fast-forward-git/

Answer (score 1):

I don't see targetted repository in your [GitHub profile](https://github.com/fxbird). Click the icon *Create a New Repo* on top bar right to your username to create it first.

Answer (score 1):

this is a work around I'm also new to git so if we ave to manually create the directory then what's te use of executing this statement

```
"git remote add origin https://github.com/fxbird/Common-Lib.git"
```